# How create a broad sound in PRAAT?

Tags: praat

It's easy to create a "pure sound", but I'd like to **create** artificially, by defining settings, a **broad-band sound**, let's say, for example, from 100 to 2OOHz, **like a vowel formant in natural speech. Visually, it would look like a large black band in the spectrogram.** I suppose, I have to change one of parameter in the "create sound" window!?

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=synthetic+speech+primer+online&form=ANNTH1&refig=a8a027a64760450c807bbf0615b55821&pc=HCTS